# Button/function to download HTML form entries into a PDF

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a very basic HTML page that can be accessed off-line. The goal is that the user fills in a form in that HTML file and after pressing a (submit) button, the form entries are downloaded to the user's PC in PDF.

I have tried already to create something, but I cannot get further than a new window > print function, which creates a new browser screen, puts the data there and prompts the user to print it; then the user can save as PDF iso printing.
But I would like to have a button that saves the form as PDF so to not give the end user that hassle.

```
var mywindow = window.open('','PRINT','height=800,width=800');
mywindow.document.write("here all the text");
```

Comment: Not an answer but an info: Not all users would be able to Print to PDF. It depends on the Browser and OS they are using.

Comment: Hey Keerthi, Thanks for The info. I am making it in Chrome and the end user should also use it in that browser. In general it works also for Firefox and Safari.